# Li-Mak test for GARCH residuals in R

Tags: r, residuals, garch, methodology

I have conducted a realized GARCH model and want to test for ARCH effects using the Li-Mak test as I have read that it is the best one for this purpose.

I am struggling on the question if residuals or standardized residuals have to be used. Even though this is not the right platform for R questions it would be kind if anybody could give me advice if `Weighted.LM.test` from the `WeightedPortTest` package in R uses the standardized residuals automatically if I enter residuals only.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief answer to the question: raw, nonstandardized residuals should be used.

If you have a fitted GARCH model, you want the stardardized innovations to be i.i.d. Therefore, you take their sample counterparts, standardized residuals, and conduct the Li-Mak test. The test inspects presence of autocorrelation in their squares. Presence of autocorrelation (high test statistic, low $p$-value, and rejection of the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation in squares) is a sign that your GARCH model has failed to capture all autoregressive conditional heteroskedastic patterns there are.

The [description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WeightedPortTest/versions/1.0/topics/Weighted.LM.test) of the `Weighted.LM.test` function in R suggests that it takes residuals `x` and conditional variances `h.t` as inputs. I presume the function treats `x` as raw residuals that can be scaled by dividing by the square root conditional variances `sqrt(h.t)` so that standardized residuals are obtained. And indeed, there is a line of code that does that (or actually almost that) at the beginning of the function: `x <- x^2/h.t`. These `x` are *squares* of standardized residuals that are further used in calculating the autocorrelations and using the latter to construct the test statistic(s).

Comment: Somewhat related question on Stack Overflow: ["Weighted Portmanteau Test for Fitted GARCH process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292432/weighted-portmanteau-test-for-fitted-garch-process).